# Си: Удалить элементы массива, стоящие на нечетных позициях

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Не могу додуматься, как эффективно удалить элементы массива, стоящие на нечетных позициях

Comment: также, как если бы вы удаляли все элементы, только с шагом 2, а не 1

Comment: создать новый массив, в два раза меньше, скопировать туда четные. Главное с размером не промазать. Старый массив удалить

Answer (score 0):

Переместить элементы с номерами 2k в k :)

Если всего в массиве `N` элементов -

```
for(int k = 1; 2*k < N; ++k)
    a[k] = a[2*k];
```

И не забыть, что теперь в массиве в два раза меньше элементов :) - при том же размере массива.

Или использовать вариант @KoVadim - перенести нужное в новый массив.